# Stereographic projection of real numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, stereographic-projections

I have the next question about the stereographic projection: How would you find the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ which corresponds, by the stereographic projection, with the real number $-\frac{1}{4}$? (for example).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The stereographic projection maps the points of a sphere to the plane. So, there is a point $(x,y,z)$ on the sphere and a corresponding point $(x',y')$ on the plane. You have $-\frac14$ and $(x_0,y_0)$... Which one is on the sphere and which one is on the plane? Do you mean that $(-\frac14,0)$ is on the plane and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is on the sphere???

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about taking the unit circle and trying to find the equation of the line from the top of the circle through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the circle which maps to a point on the real line?

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about the unit circle and how a point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ on the circle maps to a point on the real line, in this case find the point of unit circle which corresponds to the real number -1/4.

Comment: There are more than one stereographic projections, is your circle centered at (0,0) or elsewhere, for example at (0,1)?